# Activerecord query against array column using wildcard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

So let's say i have a `Customer` model with array column `phones`.
It's pretty easy to find all customers with given phone

```rb
Customer.where('? = ANY(phones)', '+79851234567')
```

But i can't figure out how to use `LIKE` with wildcard when i want to find customers with phones similar to given one, something like:

```rb
Customer.where('ANY(phones) LIKE ?', '+7985%')
```

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.5 and Rais 4.2

Any ideas?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @CdotStrifeVII he is using postgres. check tags.

Comment: @CdotStrifeVII Postgresql. I wrote it in tags but forgot to mention in post.

Comment: `ANY` is to be used for array comparison (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-comparisons.html). What are you trying to do? Find costumer who have a phone number in that pattern?

Comment: @lcguida exactly.

Comment: And `phones` is a array? Is a String? is what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this

```
Customer.where("array_to_string(phones, ', ') like ?", '+7985%')
```

I believe this will work.

Comment: `'%+7985%'` will be the correct way, i believe. For cases like
`['+7921123456', '+7985123456']`

Answer (score 2):

I think, first of all, its better to use second table phones with fields customer_id, phone_number. I think it's more rails way ). In this way you can use this query

```
Phone.where("phone_number LIKE ?", '%PART%').first.customer
```

If you serialize your array in some text field, by example JSON, you should use % on both sides of your pattern:

```
Customer.where('phones LIKE ?', '%+7985%')
```

If you have an array in your database, you should use **unnest()** function to expand an array to a set of rows.